# sub folder in document library as rootNode for user

Tags: alfresco-share

I want a sub folder within Document library as rootNode in Alfresco Shave 4.2

For Example In Document Library the folder path is Documents > XYZ > User1. When user accesses Document Library by default the content in Documents > XYZ > User1 should be displayed instead of content in Document. If we customize rootNode property from below code which is part of toobar.get.js it should work..I replaced rootNode with XYZ and it works. But rootNode="XYZ/User1" does not work

Not sure how to speciy the sub folder ?

```
var docListToolbar = {
  id: "DocListToolbar", 
  name: "Alfresco.DocListToolbar",
  options: {
    siteId: (page.url.templateArgs.site != null) ? page.url.templateArgs.site :"",
    rootNode: toolbar.rootNode != null ? toolbar.rootNode : "",
    hideNavBar: Boolean(toolbar.preferences.hideNavBar),
    googleDocsEnabled: toolbar.googleDocsEnabled,
    repositoryBrowsing: toolbar.rootNode != null,
    useTitle: (useTitle == "true"),
    syncMode: toolbar.syncMode != null ? toolbar.syncMode : "",
    createContentByTemplateEnabled: model.createContentByTemplateEnabled,
    createContentActions: model.createContent
  }
};
model.widgets = [docListToolbar];
```

since edit online is not present in My Files we created a cutom site in Alfreso Share as a custom My Files section.

Comment: I am also looking for the same...

Comment: @kheya let me know what you are trying to accomplish  do you want to have edit online in share ? We created a custom site and renamed it as My Files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late but I would suggest to create a custom site page, almost the same as document library, but with changed root node. And then you can easily replace Document Library page with custom one in site settings.

I have a quite nice example here: http://streetturtle.ninja/jekyll/update/2014/10/23/alf-custom-doclibrary-site-page/. It is almost the same as you want, but the root node changes according to the logged user.